# MongoDB Aggregation with Sum and Multiple Group Results

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have these collections members and positions

```json
[
    {
        "church":"60dbb265a75a610d90b45c6b", "parentId":"60dbb265a75a610d90b45c6b", name: "Jonah John", status: 1, birth: "1983-01-01", position: "60f56f59-08be-49ec-814a-2a421f21bc08"
    },
    {
        "church":"60dbb265a75a610d90b45c6b", "parentId":"60dbb265a75a610d90b45c6b", name: "March John", status: 1, birth: "1981-01-23", position: "60f56f59-08be-49ec-814a-2a421f21bc08"
    },
    {
        "church":"60dbb265a75a610d90b45c6b", "parentId":"60dbb265a75a610d90b45c6b",name: "Jessy John", status: 0, birth: "1984-08-01", position: "e5bba609-082c-435a-94e3-0997fd229851"
    }
]

[
    {_id: "60f56f59-08be-49ec-814a-2a421f21bc08", name: "Receptionist"},
    {_id: "5c78ba5a-3e6c-4d74-8d4a-fa23d02b8003", name: "Curtain"},
    {_id: "e5bba609-082c-435a-94e3-0997fd229851", name: "Doorman"}
]
```

I want to aggregate in a way I can get:

- **inactiveMembers**
- **activeMembers**
- **totalMembers**
- **totalPositionsOcuppied**

And two arrays with:

- **positionsOcuppied** {name, quantity}
- **birthdays** {month, quantity.

I need an output like this:

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "church":"60dbb265a75a610d90b45c6b",
        "parentId":"60dbb265a75a610d90b45c6b"
    },
    "inactiveMembers":1,
    "activeMembers":2,
    "totalMembers":3,
    "birthdays": [
        {january:2}, {august:1}
    ],
    "positionsOcuppied": [
        {Doorman: 1}, {Receptionist:2}
    ],
    "totalPositionsOcuppied": 3
}
```

How can I do that?

**PS.: Very sorry for unclear values...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

1. `$addFields` with `birthMonth` string
2. `$lookup` to add `positions`
3. `$facet` to `$group` by `birthdays`, `positionsOcuppied`, and all docs tougher as `other`
4. `$map` to format `birthdays` and `positionsOcuppied`
5. Format the answer

```
db.people.aggregate([
  {$addFields: {
      birthMonth: {
        $arrayElemAt: [  
["","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],
          {$month: {$toDate: "$birth"}}
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {$lookup: {from: "positions", localField: "position", foreignField: "_id",
      as: "position"}},
  {$facet: {
      birthdays: [{$group: {_id: "$birthMonth", count: {$sum: 1}}}],
      positionsOcuppied: [{$group: {_id: {$first: "$position.name"}, count: {$sum: 1}}}],
      other: [
        {$group: {_id: 0, 
            activeMembers: {$sum: "$status"},
            totalMembers: {$sum: 1},
            church: {$first: "$church"},
            parentId: {$first: "$parentId"},
            totalPositionsOcuppied: {$sum: {$size: "$position"}}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {$set: {
      birthdays: {
        $map: {input: "$birthdays", in: [{k: "$$this._id", v: "$$this.count"}]}
      },
      positionsOcuppied: {
        $map: {input: "$positionsOcuppied", in: [{k: "$$this._id", v: "$$this.count"}]}
      },
      other: {$first: "$other"}
    }
  },
  {$set: {
      "other.birthdays": {
        $map: {input: "$birthdays", in: {$arrayToObject: "$$this"}}
      },
      "other.positionsOcuppied": {
        $map: {input: "$positionsOcuppied", in: {$arrayToObject: "$$this"}}
      },
      "other.inactiveMembers": {
        $subtract: ["$other.totalMembers", "$other.activeMembers"]
      },
      "other._id": {church: "$other.church", parentId: "$other.parentId"},
      birthdays: "$$REMOVE",
      "other.church": "$$REMOVE",
      "other.parentId": "$$REMOVE",
      positionsOcuppied: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  },
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$other"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mDGkAL4daEd)

Comment: I've updated the question trying to clarify it. I hope now it is more understandable.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly